# What is the direction of $\vec r_{21}$ (position vector)? towards $\vec r_{2}$ or towards $\vec r_{1}$?

Tags: vectors, conventions, notation, coulombs-law, displacement

The vector representation of Coulomb's law uses a vector between the position vectors of the charges at rest. However, my teacher and a few books use the convention that vector $\vec r_{21} = \vec r_1 - \vec r_2$, while other books use the convention that,
$ \vec r_{12} = \vec r_1 - \vec r_2$. Which is correct? Or can I use either convention as long as I specify which one I'm using?

Answer (score 1):

As you have discovered, different authors have different choices of the convention. So in a sense, you have to look up the convention picked by the author in any given textbook.

It is preferable for the notation to be $\vec r_{12} = \vec r_2 - \vec r_1$ because this is closer to the mathematical notation of $\vec{PQ} = \vec{OQ} - \vec{OP}$, but as you have seen, there are plenty of people who have chosen the opposite sign convention. The reason for them to write that way is because $\vec r_{12} = \vec r_1 - \vec r_2$ has a nicer index flow. I would like to burn them all but alas, they have their own free speech rights.

Luckily, as you go to university level physics and above, the standard notation is much more common.

Comment: I like your sense of humour at the end ;)

Answer (score 0):

Focus on the PHYSICS first, then the notation.

Coulomb's Law is $$\vec F_{on\ q1\ by\ q2}=k\frac{q_1 q_2}{r_{12}^2} \hat r_{at\ q1\ pointing\ away\ from\ q2},$$
which describes a force on q1, implicitly using the electric field of q2 at q1's location. $r_{12}$ is the distance between the point charges, which I regard as the distance from the "source" q2 to the field point at q1's location ( the magnitude of the displacement vector from the source q2 to the field at q1).

I think merely using "12" alone, without further specification,
doesn't fully describe the situation.

Answer (score 0):

They are two possible conventional choices, differing for the sign. Of course, once one choice has been done, signs in the formulae should vary consistently to preserve the physics behind it. A convention can't change an attractive force into a repulsive one.

Answer (score 0):

Its a convention don't worry too much on that but the possible suggestion is go with the book (I believe from your  question since I also had the same doubt) is NCERT.

$r_{21}$ is defined from $r_{1}$ to $r_{2}$ so
$r_{21} = r_{2} -r_{1} $ as we take final $-$ initial
same way
$r_{12} = r_{1} -r_{2} $

If you mention this clearly or the other convention clearly when you answer questions it should be fine