# What is the generally accepted convention for potential difference $V_{AB}$? $V_A - V_B$ or $V_B - V_A$?

Tags: electrostatics, electric-circuits, potential, voltage, conventions

I already asked the question very clearly in the topic, so I will use this place to explain the context for which I present this question.

Normally, since I have been doing electrostatics, I have become familiar with
$$V_{AB} = V_B - V_A$$
I am now dealing with a circuit diagram in which a $6\Omega$ and a $2\Omega$ resistors are connected in parallel to an $8\Omega$ and a $12\Omega$ resistor. They are also in parallel with a 12V battery. B is a midpoint between the $6\Omega$ and the $2\Omega$ resistors and D is a midpoint between an $8\Omega$ and a $12\Omega$ resistor. We are now asked to find the potential difference between B and D. A is the point of parallel connection to the positive plate of the battery and C is to the negative.

This is the step I took, I considered the connection as a potential divider and so I used that to get $V_{AB} = 9V, V_{AC} = 4.8V$. Please draw the diagram to see this. With that we get to the point of diversion from my solution and that of the textbook, and it matters because they asked which potential is higher $V_B$ or $V_D$.

I did
$$V_{AB} = V_B - V_A = 9Volts$$
$$V_{AD} = V_D - V_A = 4.8Volts$$
Subtracting 2 from 1
$$V_B - V_D = 9 - 4.8 = 4.2Volts$$
My answer now becomes that the potential difference $V_{BD} = -4.2volts$ and that the potential of B is greater than that of D.

But the textbook uses the first definition of $V_{AB}$ and concludes that the potential difference between B and D is 4.2volts and that the potential of D is greater. No doubts, I am wrong somehow, but where did I get it wrong?

Comment: I understand that the 6$\Omega$ and 2$\Omega$ resistors would be in series with each other.  From calculations, I can tell that the 8$\Omega$ and 12$\Omega$ resistors are also in series.  Please specify in each branch of the parallel circuit which resistor is closer to the positive terminal of the battery.

Comment: 6 is closer in the first and 8 is closer in the second to the positive terminal, @KenMellendorf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using the voltage across a resistor in the Ohm's Law, the potential difference across the resistor is traditionally a potential drop in the direction of the current.  When looking at voltage across a battery, the potential difference is traditionally an emf or voltage gain.  Electric potential rises as current passes through the battery from (-) to (+).  The electric potential then falls as the current passes through the resistor, from the (+) end of the battery to the (-) end of the battery.  So as to avoid negative electric potentials at any individual point, tradition is to make the electric potential zero at the (-) end of the DC power source such as a battery.  This then makes $V_A$ equal to twelve volts.  $V_B$ and $V_C$ have decreased toward zero due to the potential drops across the 6$\Omega$ and 8$\Omega$ resistors.

Answer (score 1):

Take the negative plate, i.e. C, as grounded to 0V, A = +12V.

Then $V_{AB} = V_B - V_A = -9V$, $V_B = +3V$, etc. I think you can understand the rest. You merely made a silly little sign mistake.

I nearly sent you to my other answer talking about conventions: https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/760896/364064

Comment: what do you mean by grounded to 0volts?

Comment: Set the voltage of that plate to 0V

Answer (score 1):

You wrote $V_{\rm AD} = V_{\rm D} - V_{\rm A} = 4.8\,\rm V$.

You then worked out $V_{\rm B} - V_{\rm D} = 9 - 4.8 = 4.2\,\rm V$.

Look at the subscripts for the first equation $\rm AD \to D-A$.

Thus the subscripts for the second equation should be $\rm DB \to B-D$ which means that you have found $V_{\rm DB} = 4.2\,\rm V$, ie the potential of node $D$ is greater than that of node $B$.

Conversely with $V_{\rm BD} = -4.2\,\rm V$, the potential of node $B$ is less than the potential of node $D$.

Annotating a circuit diagram sometimes help to clarify the situation.

[image]